# MySQL: How to select a preferred value from multiple rows (and fall back to a default)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query which returns a list of group ids that are attached to the product ids specified in the IN clause.

```sql
SELECT t1.product_id, t2.group_id  
FROM table_1 t1  
LEFT JOIN table_2 t2  
ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id  
WHERE t1.product_id IN(1,2,3,4,5)  
AND t2.group_id = -1  
OR t2.group_id = 2
```

This is returning something like this:

```
+------------+----------+
| product_id | group_id |
+------------+----------+
| 1          | -1       |
| 1          |  2       |
| 2          | -1       |
| 3          | -1       |
| 4          | -1       |
| 5          | -1       |
+------------+----------+
```

The group_id will always have a default value of -1 but in some cases there may be more than one value (eg, product_id '1' has a group_id of '-1' and '2').  What I want to do is ignore the '-1' value when there is an alternative so I end up with this:

```
+------------+----------+
| product_id | group_id |
+------------+----------+
| 1          |  2       |
| 2          | -1       |
| 3          | -1       |
| 4          | -1       |
| 5          | -1       |
+------------+----------+
```

I've tried using a GROUP BY statement on the product_id but I just end up with the -1 values in the group_id column.

Please could somebody give me some pointers on how I might be able to do this!

Comment: Is there any reason to JOIN since the product_id exists in both tables?

Comment: What should happen if a product is related to two `group_id`s, say `2` and `3`, besides `-1`?

Comment: Nice question. If the max values are two (-1, other number) query code can be very simple

Comment: Something else to consider is whether or not you still require the default relationship to be stored once you have a non-default value.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.product_id, MAX(t2.group_id)  
FROM table_1 t1 , table_2 t2   
WHERE t1.product_id IN(1,2,3,4,5) 
AND t1.product_id = t2.product_id 
AND t2.group_id = -1  
OR t2.group_id = 2
GROUP BY (t1.product_id)
```

Try this. This will return 2 if both -1 and 2 are available. ie, I just select the max of the available group ids. Hope this is what you need here

Comment: The answer will be 3, according to the OP, if there is no group associated with the product then the group id is -1, if anything is associated he wants "to ignore -1 and give the group id". So, this gives a group id when atleast one group is associated with the product

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.product_id, COALESCE(MAX(t2.group_id ),-1) AS group_id -- if there is no group id default to -1
FROM table_1 t1  
LEFT JOIN table_2 t2  
ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id  
WHERE t1.product_id IN(1,2,3,4,5)  
AND t2.group_id IN (-1, 2)
GROUP BY t1.product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this sql:

```
SELECT t1.product_id, t2.group_id  
FROM table_1 t1  
LEFT JOIN (SELECT product_id, MAX(group_id) AS group_id
           FROM table_2
           WHERE group_id IN (-1,2)
           GROUP BY product_id) t2 ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id  
WHERE t1.product_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
SELECT product_id, group_id= '-1' From products GROUP BY product_id HAVING COUNT(product_id) = 1 
UNION 
SELECT product_id, MAX(group_id) FROM products GROUP BY product_id HAVING COUNT(product_id) > 1
```

Comment: Hi @sudheshna, are you sure that this sql works for this question?

Comment: yes it will work, first query will return all the records with single group id (-1) and the second will return the max of group_id for those having multiple group_ids

Comment: Hi @sudheshna, you really read the question? @Tom works with two tables and he need that the results don't repeat the value of product_id. Your sql assumes that the value of group_id is equal to -1 with product_id = 1, and he needs just the opposite. Where's the two tables in the sql?

Comment: Hi @doctore, no, he can use the join query if he want, also its not checking product_id = 1, have you read the query well, its checking whether the count of the product_id is one so that the group_id is -1 as per his question. Else it will take the max of group_ids among the group ids, I have checked this and is working fine for me